# Can I store executable code in Core Data

Tags: core-data

I have an app that lets the user interact with several forms. I can easily get everything I need to create a form via a request to a remote server. But, each form needs its own class to handle input, data formatting and validation, display, and local storage. I have tried to write a generic class that can work for ANY form, but am running into many one-off situations. Also, if I change or add forms in the future with their own special cases, I don't want to have to revise the code and issue an update.

Is it possible to serialize compiled code, send it in a server request, and store it in Core Data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it's certainly possible, it's also certainly quite complex. You'll have to deal with many low level considerations, per example dynamically linking your code fragments.

As I understand, you do not need tons of code, and nothing excessively complex. It's probably much easier then to use a scripting language you can embed in your application, like say, JavaScript, or Lua with a little more effort. Lua ain't big and you can use precompiled fragments very easily.